# How to prove that the cross product of two vectors is a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, cross-product

I'm stuck, could I please have a hint?

Comment: It's a bilinear transformation on the pair of vectors; it's a linear transformation on the tensor product of two vectors. $\qquad$

Comment: @DerickWhat is a bilinear transformation? What are tensor products?

Comment: Given a specific vector, $v$, the transformation $L(x) = v\times x$ will indeed be linear.  If you can come up with a matrix such that if you multiply a vector by, the result is the cross product of the vector, then that acts as sufficient proof that it is a linear transformation.

Comment: @Derick : A bilinear transformation is a function of two vector variables that is linear in each variable separately. That means if you hold one of them constant and let the other one vary, then it's a linear function of that other one.  The difference between an ordered pair of vectors and a tensor product of vectors is that if you multiply one of the vectors by a nonzero scalar and the other by the reciprocal of that scalar, then you get a different ordered pair but the same tensor product. $\qquad$

Comment: @Derick To the question about orthogonality, no... why would it?  You are able to take the cross product of any two vectors, whether they are orthogonal or not.  For the second, it is more than just that.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I understand that it the following may just be a more limited statement of your comment, but would you agree that "a linear transformation on the *wedge product* of two vectors" is most fitting? [Not a rhetorical or facetious question.]

Answer (score 10):

(*tacitly assuming that we are working with the traditional cross product of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$*)

Assuming that one of the vectors is held constant.  Let $v$ be the fixed vector.  We wish to prove that $L(x) = v\times x$ is a linear transformation of $x$ from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Let $v = \begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}$.  Let $x = \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$.

The cross product $v\times x = \det\left(\begin{bmatrix}\hat{i}&\hat{j}&\hat{k}\\
v_1&v_2&v_3\\x_1&x_2&x_3\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}v_2x_3-v_3x_2\\-v_1x_3+v_3x_1\\v_1x_2-v_2x_1\end{bmatrix} = x_1\begin{bmatrix}0\\v_3\\-v_2\end{bmatrix}+x_2\begin{bmatrix}-v_3\\0\\v_1\end{bmatrix}+x_3\begin{bmatrix}\star\\\star\\\star\end{bmatrix}$

Letting you fill in the $\star$'s above yourself.

How can we construct a matrix then such that $Ax = v\times x$?

If we successfully construct such a matrix, then that shows that the transformation is indeed a linear transformation.

Comment: Solution in the back of the book: The transformation matrix is then: $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & - v_3 &  v_2 \\  v_3 & 0 & -v_1 \\ - v_2 & v_1 & 0\end{bmatrix},$$ naturally resulting from packing the three column vectors into a single matrix.

Answer (score 1):

For a function $L: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ to be a linear transformation, you have to verify two properties:

1. $L(a \overrightarrow{v})=aL(\overrightarrow{v})$ for any scalar $a$ and any vector $\overrightarrow{v}$
2. $L(\overrightarrow{v}+\overrightarrow{w})=L(\overrightarrow{v})+L(\overrightarrow{w})$ for any two vectors $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $\overrightarrow{w}$

In this case, fix some vector $\overrightarrow{u}$, and consider the linear transformation defined by $L(\overrightarrow{v})= \overrightarrow{u} \times \overrightarrow{v}$.  To show that the cross-product is linear, you need to show that properties (1) and (2) above hold; in other words, you need to verify that:

1. $\overrightarrow{u} \times (a\overrightarrow{v})=a ( \overrightarrow{u} \times \overrightarrow{v})$
2. $\overrightarrow{u} \times (\overrightarrow{v} + \overrightarrow{w})=(\overrightarrow{u}\times \overrightarrow{v})+(\overrightarrow{u}\times \overrightarrow{w})$

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $\vec{a}\times(\vec{b} + \vec{c}) = \vec{a}\times\vec{b} + \vec{a}\times\vec{c}$, we have to make these vectors in Caertesian component using an orthonormal natural base $\{\hat{x}_j ~|~ j = 1, 2, 3\}$. I shall use Einstein Summation Convention, that is $\vec{a} = a_j\hat{x}_j$, $\vec{b} = b_j\hat{x}_j$, and $\vec{c} = c_j\hat{x}_j$, without summation symbol $\sum$.  Now, we get

\begin{align}
& \vec{a}\times(\vec{b} + \vec{c}) \\[6pt]
= {} & a_j\hat{x}_j\times\hat{x}_k(b_k + c_k) \\[6pt]
= {} & a_j(b_k + c_k)\hat{x}_j\times\hat{x}_k \\[6pt]
= {} & (a_jb_k + a_jc_k)\hat{x}_j\times\hat{x}_k \\[6pt]
= {} & a_jb_k\hat{x}_j\times\hat{x}_k + a_jc_k\hat{x}_j\times\hat{x}_k \\[6pt]
= {} & (a_j\hat{x}_j)\times(b_k\hat{x}_k) + (a_j\hat{x}_j)\times(c_k\hat{x}_k) \\[6pt]
= {} & \vec{a}\times\vec{b} + \vec{a}\times\vec{c}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Cross product between vector $\vec{A}$ dan $\vec{B}$ is defined by
\begin{equation}
\vec{A}\times\vec{B} := |\vec{A}||\vec{B}|\sin\angle(\vec{A},\vec{B})\frac{\vec{A}\times\vec{B}}{|\vec{A}\times\vec{B}|}.
\end{equation}
Because for $\vec{A} := (A_x,A_y,A_z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\vec{B} := (B_x,B_y,B_z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, it yields
\begin{eqnarray}
\sin\angle(\vec{A},\vec{B}) &=& \sqrt{1 - \cos^2\angle(\vec{A},\vec{B})} 
= \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}}{|\vec{A}||\vec{B}|}\right)^2} 
= \frac{\sqrt{|\vec{A}|^2|\vec{B}|^2 - (\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B})^2}}{|\vec{A}||\vec{B}|} \nonumber\\
&=& \frac{\sqrt{(A_x^2 + A_y^2 + A_z^2)(B_x^2 + B_y^2 + B_z^2) - (A_xB_x + A_yB_y + A_zB_z)^2}}{|\vec{A}||\vec{B}|} \nonumber\\
&=& \frac{\sqrt{(A_yB_z - A_zB_y)^2 + (A_zB_x - A_xB_z)^2 + (A_xB_y - A_yB_x)^2}}{|\vec{A}||\vec{B}|},
\end{eqnarray}
so
\begin{equation}
\vec{A}\times\vec{B} = \sqrt{(A_yB_z - A_zB_y)^2 + (A_zB_x - A_xB_z)^2 + (A_xB_y - A_yB_x)^2}\frac{\vec{A}\times\vec{B}}{|\vec{A}\times\vec{B}|},
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
|\vec{A}\times\vec{B}| = \sqrt{(A_yB_z - A_zB_y)^2 + (A_zB_x - A_xB_z)^2 + (A_xB_y - A_yB_x)^2}.
\label{201810211741}
\end{equation}
There is many possibility of explicit form of $\vec{A}\times\vec{B}$ which satisfy equation (\ref{201810211741}).
Because $\hat{x}\times\hat{y} = \hat{z}$, $\hat{z}\times\hat{x} = \hat{y}$, and $\hat{y}\times\hat{z} = \hat{x}$ must be satisfied, so it must be
\begin{equation}
\vec{A}\times\vec{B} = (A_yB_z - A_zB_y)\hat{x} + (A_zB_x - A_xB_z)\hat{y} + (A_xB_y - A_yB_x)\hat{z}.
\end{equation}